# Error when trying to run RuboCop in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jetbrains-ide, rubymine, rubocop

I have an error within RubyMine that RuboCop cannot execute, it displays this message:

> Error:/home/daniel/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.8/bin/ruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)

I've tried everything.

I also noticed that sometimes this same message happens with rake.

I'm on Kubuntu 22.04 using

- asdf
- ruby 2.7.8
- rails 6.0.2.1

I'm running RubyMine directly through the `./rubymine.sh` terminal to get some environment variables.

I hope you can run RuboCop in RubyMine.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to run RuboCop in RubyMine. The error you mentioned, though, looks like the one reported also without RubyMine. Could you take a look at
https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/64

Comment: ok, I had already seen this git post, but I still couldn't do it.  Could this be an asdf problem?

Comment: 2023-10-19 08:43:28,449 [  17791]   WARN - #o.j.p.r.r.i.r.RubocopResponse - RuboCop execution error
/home/daniel/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.8/bin/ruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)